# How to value part of character value with another variable in R

Tags: r

I have `x1 <- 5`, `x2 <- "this number is "` variables.

Is there a way to write it like this? (without using `paste()` function)  `x3 <- "this number 'x1' "`
and give result  `"this number is 5 "`

Comment: Why do you need this stored in a variable? Why not store the value in the variable and then print the text plus value when you need it?

Comment: because  goal is to be able to change some parameters in my base table instead of printing it and then insert it differently with a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cat` function will do it:

```
cat(x2, x1)
#this number is  5
```

The `cat` function is different than the `print` function in many ways but the two biggest in my mind are that `cat` returns NULL and does not quote by default, whereas `print` returns its first argument and does quote by default. The `cat` function is used entirely for its side-effect of output to a device. `print` on the other hand is often used as a way of both returning a value and put text to a device.